# Antd, `tsc` get error: Interface 'TreeProps<T>' incorrectly extends interface 'Omit<TreeProps<T>

Tags: reactjs, typescript, package, antd, npm-package

I want to create react package that use Antd inside project, but when I run `npm run build` it return this error on `tsc` step

Error

```
node_modules/antd/lib/tree-select/index.d.ts:18:18 - error TS2430: Interface 'TreeSelectProps<ValueType, OptionType>' incorrectly extends interface 'Omit<TreeSelectProps<ValueType, OptionType>, "mode" | "getInputElement" | "inputIcon" | "backfill" | "showTreeIcon" | "treeMotion" | "treeLine">'.
  Types of property 'switcherIcon' are incompatible.
    Type 'SwitcherIcon' is not assignable to type 'IconType'.
      Type '(props: { expanded: boolean; }) => ReactNode' is not assignable to type 'IconType'.
        Type '(props: { expanded: boolean; }) => ReactNode' is not assignable to type '(props: TreeNodeProps<DataNode>) => ReactNode'.
          Types of parameters 'props' and 'props' are incompatible.
            Type 'TreeNodeProps<DataNode>' is not assignable to type '{ expanded: boolean; }'.
              Types of property 'expanded' are incompatible.
                Type 'boolean | undefined' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
                  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.

18 export interface TreeSelectProps<ValueType = any, OptionType extends BaseOptionType | DefaultOptionType = DefaultOptionType> extends Omit<RcTreeSelectProps<ValueType, OptionType>, 'showTreeIcon' | 'treeMotion' | 'inputIcon' | 'mode' | 'getInputElement' | 'backfill' | 'treeLine'> {
                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/antd/lib/tree/Tree.d.ts:86:18 - error TS2430: Interface 'TreeProps<T>' incorrectly extends interface 'Omit<TreeProps<T>, "direction" | "draggable" | "prefixCls" | "showLine">'.
  Types of property 'icon' are incompatible.
    Type 'ReactNode | ((nodeProps: AntdTreeNodeAttribute) => ReactNode)' is not assignable to type 'IconType'.
      Type '(nodeProps: AntdTreeNodeAttribute) => ReactNode' is not assignable to type 'IconType'.
        Type '(nodeProps: AntdTreeNodeAttribute) => ReactNode' is not assignable to type '(props: TreeNodeProps<DataNode>) => ReactNode'.
          Types of parameters 'nodeProps' and 'props' are incompatible.
            Type 'TreeNodeProps<DataNode>' is not assignable to type 'AntdTreeNodeAttribute'.
              Types of property 'eventKey' are incompatible.
                Type 'Key | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
                  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.

86 export interface TreeProps<T extends BasicDataNode = DataNode> extends Omit<RcTreeProps<T>, 'prefixCls' | 'showLine' | 'direction' | 'draggable'> {
                    ~~~~~~~~~
```

In my package.json

```
{ 
         "main": "dist/index.js",
         "typings": "dist/index.d.ts",
          "dependencies": {
         "@babel/polyfill": "^7.12.1",
         "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
         "@testing-library/react": "^13.3.0",
         "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
         "@types/jest": "^27.5.2",
         "@types/node": "^16.11.41",
         "@types/react": "^18.0.14",
         "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.5",
         "antd": "^4.16.0",
         "react": "^18.2.0",
         "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
         "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
         "styled-components": "^5.3.5",
         "ts-loader": "^9.3.0",
         "typescript": "^4.7.3",
         "web-vitals": "^2.1.4",
         "webpack": "^5.73.0",
         "webpack-cli": "^4.10.0"
       },
       "scripts": {
         "start": "react-scripts start",
         "emit-types": "tsc",
         "emit": "tsc --outDir dist --declaration --emitDeclarationOnly",
         "build": "babel src/lib --out-dir dist --extensions '.ts,.tsx' && npm run emit-types && NODE_ENV=production webpack",
         "test": "react-scripts test",
         "eject": "react-scripts eject"
       },
     }
```

[error_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wTHPt.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I've just had the same issue, adding

```
skipLibCheck:true
```

in my tsconfig.json solved the issue

I hope you fixed you issue already but in case someone else is facing the same issue, i'm sharing how i solved it, it might help

Comment: Thank you very much!! I used this too, after facing this issue for days. :))

Comment: @RayRookies Welcome to StackOverflow! I see you haven't taken the [tour] yet. Specifically, please see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).